# How to avoid shared state?

Tags: node.js, race-condition

I have read many times that I should avoid shared state to avoid race conditions either in asynchronous programming or in multi threading.

So for example if I had a program that kept fetching data from external server and updated an object in memory and on user request I would send that object from memory.

How would I change the behaviour of such program to not use shared state?

I can't think of any way that makes sense. Have I misunderstood the idea of not using shared state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared state / race conditions is more of a concern for what information you do not want to lose.

Using your example, it could be reasonable for a user to update his own login settings, and for you to send an updated version of the user object from in-memory to the database. This is reasonable because a user can't update their own login settings from two computers at the same time.

On the other hand, if you had an object with a counter to count the total number of visits to your website, it would not be advisable to send that in-memory object to be written to the database.  This would be 'shared state' and so many users would need to write to that variable at the same time, that surely it would get out of date.  For example, I might be the 5th visitor to the website, but due to my slow internet, you visit the website in the meantime and write `5` to the database. I only queried the database when I started looking at the page, so have an object with `4` in the counter, so I write `5` to the database after you, which effectually invalidates your visit to the site.  Instead, you would want to tally site visits on the server side, and just add +1 for ever hit you receive (and wrap this in thread-safe, synchronous code).

Comment: But if I want to update the object using existing info from that object, I would have to get the latest copy of that object or lock that object for any changes, right?

Comment: not necessarily.  If it's something like a user's metadata, you probably don't care if you overwrite the whole thing.